# How to get the call stack of a specified process which run on user space in android?

Tags: android, linux, debugging, process

I knew there are some ways to get the call stack

1. using "dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file" to get the stack of **kernel thread**
2. or using backtrack to get the stack of **current process**.

But now I need to trace a **user space** process, with many child process (**thread**) only when some special event happened, by another process (we can treat it as a temporary debugger). Is there any way to do such things?

ptrace (http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) is a good suggestion but seems no way to trace thread?

**update**

1. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html It seem "every thread can be individually attached to a (potentially different) tracer"!?
2. I have tried to use ptrace to get the stack of the process. but I found I have no permission? I use

   > ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, tid2, NULL, NULL);

   but -1 is return, and errno is 1(**Operation not permitted**)

   Do I miss something?
3. I work on an android platform. It seems I have no permission to attach some process?   (gdb tool is root, but my app is not.)

Comment: This will only really work on your own code or on a rooted device.

Comment: yes. It is. I can compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach to a process, there MUST be a parent/child relationship between you process and that to be attached, or your process run as root.